# Drush Command for Installing core

Tags: drush, installation

Is there a simple `drush site-install` script for Drupal 8? I've gotten very used to running the following script to install Drupal.

```
drush site-install standard --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin --db-url=mysql://username:password@localhost/sitename -y;
```

Comment: In the end this didn't actually change from how it was in Drupal 7 (Drush 8 or earlier). Your sample command would now probably run just fine again. See https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/site/site:install/

Answer (score 2):

I manage to install Drupal 8 with Drush after creating the project with Composer from [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project). Steps I take are as follows:

1. Create project with dev dependencies:

`composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev directory-name --stability dev --no-interaction`

2. Create site-database for the project.
3. Run **inside web folder**:

`../vendor/bin/drush site:install standard --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin --db-url=mysql://username:password@localhost/site-database -y`

Answer (score 0):

[`drush site:install`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/site/site:install/) or `drush si` seems to work as intended.  You can also use `drush make` to download the core files and any other modules that you need.